# kubernetes mongo docker authentication does not work with custom config file

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I have created pod with below pod definition which uses mongo official docker image. The expected result here is mongo docker creates user and pwd with env variables `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME`  and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` and then it will use `/etc/mongo/mongod.conf` provided to it from volume. Instead what happens is - on first connection - I am unable to connect saying user does not exist.

The error disappears if I remove the `command` section. Any Idea how to resolve this issue.

The equivalent docker command works well, but in kubernetes auth does not work if I provide a custom configuration file.

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret --name some-mongo -v /etc/mongo:/etc/mongo -v /etc/ssl/keyfile:/data/db/keyfile  mongo:4.2.23 --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    db: mongodb
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mongodb
      image: mongo:4.2.23
      command:
           - mongod
           - "--config"
           - "/etc/mongo/mongod.conf"
      env:
       - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
         valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongosecret
              key: user

       - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
         valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongosecret
              key: password
      volumeMounts:
          - name: mongodb-keyfile
            mountPath: /etc/ssl
          - name: mongodb-config
            mountPath: /etc/mongo
            readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: mongodb-keyfile
      secret:
        secretName: mongodb-keyfile
        defaultMode: 0600
    - name: mongodb-config
      configMap:
        name: mongodb-config
```

Comment: Please post how you create the secrets in kubernetes (yaml or kubectl) and how you generate the config files. You should also better use a deployment instead of using a pod. Did you consider where your DB data will be stored. You need a volume to hold them or you will losse every time all when your pod restarts.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62018646/unable-to-authenticate-mongodb-deployed-in-kubernetes) , As you said Post removing  “command”  from deployment file and it is working Because when you set MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD ENV variables in your manifest. Mongo container will enable --auth by itself. So, you don't need to specify explicitly and check here.

Refer to this [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559557/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-through-docker) , [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815216/authentication-mongo-deployed-on-kubernetes) for more information. You can also pass the username and password as [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#docker-config-secrets) .